# In a Git repository the untracked files in branch-1 still appear in branch-2

Tags: git

I have a repository with two branches; master and gh-pages.
When I switch from gh-pages to master, the untracked files ( included in .gitignore) still appear in the working directory of the master branch.
Recently, I transferred the repository from an old pc to a new one by copying the repository folder including all subfolders.
I can't remember exactly how the case was on the old PC.

What should I do to eliminate this disturbing appearance?

Comment: Also answered in [the Git FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#How_do_I_remove_my_uncommitted_changes_from_branch_A_and_add_them_to_a_new_branch_B.3F)—though from a somewhat different perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Untracked files are not in any branch.  This behavior is therefore entirely normal.  You will need to get accustomed to it.

#### Long-ish

It's worth noting that *none of your work-tree files are in branches*.  *Some* of the files are *copied from* ... well, not *branches* really, but rather *commits*.  But all of the files that are in your work-tree (or *working tree*, if you prefer this term) are outside the Git repository in the first place.

To make sense of this, we must define the term *repository* more precisely.  A Git repository consists primarily of two databases:

- One—which is usually the largest by far—contains Git's *objects*.  Objects are a general term for Git's commits, trees, blobs (file content), and annotated tags.  Git stores these in special, read-only, compressed form.  Only Git can actually *use* these objects.  You normally deal only with these Git objects at the level of commits (or occasionally, tags).

  This database is a simple key-value store.  The keys are Git object hash IDs.  The values are the read-only objects.
- The second database maps names, such as branch or tag names, to hash IDs.  This database is also a simple key-value store; the keys this time are the names, and the values are hash IDs, which are then used as keys in the first database.

There are additional files, such as reflogs and various other internal files, including Git's *index* or *staging area*.  All of these are located in the `.git` directory.  So the repository proper consists of everything in the `.git` directory.  A `git clone` operation copies the object database, and reads (but normally does *not* copy directly) the name database; the remaining repository data are all private and are not copied by cloning.

Because files stored within commits (as tree and blob objects) are in a special Git-only format, and frozen for all time, Git has to *copy* the files that are in a commit—the snapshot part of any given commit—into an area where the files are turned into ordinary files that can be read or written by any program on your computer.  So Git will *extract* the committed copies of files into ordinary, read/write files.  These files are *not in the repository:* instead, Git copies them to your *work-tree* or *working tree*.

When you switch from one branch to another, you also usually switch from one *commit* to another.  That's because checking out a branch by name means checking out the *tip commit* of that branch—i.e., the hash ID stored in the names database.  When you do this, Git will *remove* from your work-tree any file that came out of the old commit—the one you are switching away from—but is not in the new commit that you are switching to.  Git will replace, in your work-tree, any file that is different in the two commits.  Git will add to your work-tree any file that is in the commit you are switching to.

(This description is not quite 100% correct, but is good enough to get you started, before you get to the 100% correct variant.)

Files that are in *neither* commit are, of course, not affected by this process.  Such files are *untracked*.  (This too is not 100% correct, but good enough to get started.)  Since such a file was not in the commit you extracted earlier, *you* must have put the file there—either directly, yourself, or by running some command that created the file.

Your work-tree is yours, to do with as you like.  If you create files there that Git has never heard of, Git will leave them alone.

(Note that if you switch from, say, commit `a123456` to commit `b789abc`, it's possible for one of the two commits to have a file the other commit lacks.  In this case, a file that *isn't* in the commit you're moving to, will generally be removed from your work-tree, as noted earlier.  A file that *is* in the commit you're moving to, but is not in the commit you are moving from, will need to be created in your work-tree, as noted earlier.  Files that are identical in both commits need not be touched at all, and generally will not be.)

Comment: I would augment the sentence «When you switch from one branch to another, you also usually switch from one commit to another.» to produce «When you switch from one branch to another, you also usually switch from one commit to another—because switching to a branch, among other things, means switching to the state of its tip commit, and different branches usually have different tip commits». Otherwise it may not be entirely clear for a newcomer what is the connection.

Answer (score 4):

An untracked file is not part of the repository so it does not belong to any branch at all. That's why the file still appear regardless of branch. If you want to track it use `git add` or if you want Git to ignore the files add them to `.gitignore`

Comment: If you want to get rid of them type `git clean -f`